# How to have both positive and negative data in spy class Karma Jasmine Angular

Tags: angular, integration-testing, karma-jasmine

```
class HeroDetailServiceSpy {
  testHero: Hero = {id: 42, name: 'Test Hero' };

  /* emit cloned test hero */
  getHero = jasmine.createSpy('getHero').and.callFake(
    () => asyncData(Object.assign({}, this.testHero))
  );

  /* emit clone of test hero, with changes merged in */
  saveHero = jasmine.createSpy('saveHero').and.callFake(
    (hero: Hero) => asyncData(Object.assign(this.testHero, hero))
  );
}
```

Now when i call getHero() method i get testHero Response. But in observable both success and failure calls are there. So for success call i get these response. But how do I get for failure call.

So when i call getHero, it should return with failure and that should cover my failure loop in observable

Ref: https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests

Comment: by failure do you mean incorrect return from function call or error thrown while calling that method?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `throwError` in the `component` spec file itself by something like:

**component.spec.ts**

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';


it('should handle getHero() error response',()=>{
   spyOn(component.heroDetailService,'getHero').and.returnValue(throwError('error'));
   // do the testing and the service would return error 
})
```